# M.A.M.E. roms on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, emulator

I'm a quite recent user of the Raspberry Pi and I'd like to turn it into a retro arcade machine just like I've seen on internet. I've downloaded MAME4ALL from the PiStore as well as a package of roms. I've already used an old version of M.A.M.E. on Windows and had not any problem. It was all simple just needed to change to directory of the rom file. Whereas for the Raspberry Pi, I really don't know where to put the roms. I just want to set the directory of roms to a USB stick just like I've done with Windows. How can I do that?

Comment: What's stopping you from just putting them onto a USB stick?

Comment: @CanadianLuke I've put there but when I launch Mame, I've got an error saying "Error : There are no available games found" and the app stops working a few seconds after.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MAME is prerelease software https://meta.superuser.com/q/13276/11116

Comment: **Note to close voters:** I found no evidence that this is pre-release software. It has had numerous official major releases; in fact there was another stable release in July of this year, and  Google ported MAME to Native Client 6 yrs ago, allowing MAME to run inside Chrome.  The close vote appears to be a case of trolling the site over a disagreement referenced in the linked Meta discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAME has a configuration file that you need to edit (`mame.cfg`?) and tell it where you are putting things, like `roms`, if you don't put it in the default directories (which I have no idea what would be on Linux).

---

Check `/mnt/media` for your USB stick if the problem is you can't find what directory it mounted to.